# ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (1,) and (12,)

Tags: python, matplotlib

I think I have tried all the solutions but still get this message. I am a newbie at python. Script open up a spreadsheet and counts the number of times a month is recorded. Everything work right down to when the graph gets plotted. Then it fails. I have included the entire script and errors. At the bottom I included the printout of the y axis showing the data and the count. The script loads the form body from the mjb_4.py but all that code works and have been used before I added the code plot

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QDialog, QApplication
from mjb_4 import *
from dateutil import parser
from datetime import date, datetime, timedelta
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import openpyxl

cnt =0
filename = "mjb.xlsx"
dte = ""
mth = 0
class MyForm(QDialog):
    def __init__ (self):
        super().__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_Dialog()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.ui.calendarWidget.SelectionMode.SingleSelection
        self.ui.calendarWidget.clicked.connect(self.dat)
        self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.saveme)
        self.ui.Chart.clicked.connect(self.chrt)
        self.ui.l_file.setText(filename)
        dte = self.ui.calendarWidget.selectedDate().toString("MM/dd/yy")
        self.ui.l_date.setText(dte)
        self.show()
        self.load()

    def load(self):
        global filename
        w = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename)
        sh = w.get_sheet_by_name('data')
        cnt = sh.max_row
        cell = 'a' + str(cnt)
        ld = datetime.strptime(sh[cell].value, '%m/%d/%y')
        self.ui.l_last.setText(str(ld))
        cd = datetime.now()
        Gap=(cd - ld).days
        self.ui.l_last_2.setText(str(Gap))

    def dat(self, qDateClicked):
        global mth
        mth =  self.ui.calendarWidget.monthShown()
        dte = self.ui.calendarWidget.selectedDate().toString("MM/dd/yy")
        self.ui.l_date.setText(dte)
            
    def saveme(self):
        global mth
        global filename
        dte = self.ui.calendarWidget.selectedDate().toString("MM/dd/yy")
        wb =  openpyxl.load_workbook(filename)
        sh = wb.get_sheet_by_name('data')
        cnt = sh.max_row
        cell = 'a' + str(cnt + 1)
        sh[cell].value = dte
        cell = 'b' + str(cnt + 1)
        sh[cell].value = mth
        wb.save(filename)
        self.ui.l_file.setText('SAVED')

    def chrt(self):
        x = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12])
        y = np.array([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0])
        wb =  openpyxl.load_workbook(filename)
        sh = wb.get_sheet_by_name('data')
        cnt = sh.max_row
        for rows in range(1, cnt):
            cell = 'b' + str(rows)
            tmp = sh[cell].value
            for x in range(12):
                if tmp == x:
                    y[x-1] += 1
        print(y)
        print(len(y))
        plt.plot(x,y)
        plt.xlabel('Month')
        plt.ylabel('count')
        plt.title('Tracker')
        plt.show()
```

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/media/pi/M16/xesex/My_xeses_chart.py", line 81, in chrt
    plt.plot(x,y)
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 2813, in plot
    is not None else {}), **kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py", line 1812, in inner
    return func(ax, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py", line 1611, in plot
    for line in self._get_lines(*args, **kwargs):
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.py", line 393, in _grab_next_args
    yield from self._plot_args(this, kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.py", line 370, in _plot_args
    x, y = self._xy_from_xy(x, y)
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.py", line 231, in _xy_from_xy
    "have shapes {} and {}".format(x.shape, y.shape))
ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (1,) and (12,)
```

Comment: Don't copy all of the code, only the lines around the error. Thanks!

Comment: Your problem is that you use the variable name `x` twice: once as `x = np.array([....])` and once as the control variable in `for x in range(12):`. You need a different variable name. Furthermore, note that `for x in range(12):` goes from 0 to 11.

Comment: excellent - I totally missed that. newbie mistake.  Works perfect now - thanks